# Pandas - Filtering DataFrame based on unique value and different columns datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following datafame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': ['1','1','2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4'],
      'USER' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
      'DATE_VIEW': ['16/05/2019','18/05/2019', '16/03/2020', '18/03/2020', '16/07/2020', '21/07/2020', '13/02/2020', '14/02/2020', '15/02/2020'],
      'DATE_ACCEPT': ['17/05/2019', np.nan, np.nan, '18/03/2020', '16/07/2020', np.nan, np.nan, '14/02/2020', np.nan],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['DATE_VIEW'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_VIEW'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df['DATE_ACCEPT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_ACCEPT'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

[image]

I am looking for a way to keep for unique `df['ID']` the row if the `df['DATE_VIEW']` is smaller than the `df['DATE_VIEW']` when the `df['DATE_ACCEPT]` has been populated and drop the row it if the `df['DATE_VIEW']` is grater than the `df['DATE_VIEW']` when the `df['DATE_ACCEPT]` has been populated for that particular `df['ID']`. Expected output below:

[image]

Comment: could you explain better what you mean by populated?

Comment: for each user ID I need to keep rows where the the df['DATE_VIEW']  is equal or lower than the df['DATE_ACCEPT]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `groupby` the `ID` column and `transform` to get `DATE_ACCEPT` for each row, then compare `DATE_VIEW` to that date:

```
df.loc[df['DATE_VIEW'].le(df.groupby('ID')['DATE_ACCEPT'].transform('max'))]
```

Output:

```
  ID USER  DATE_VIEW DATE_ACCEPT
0  1    A 2019-05-16  2019-05-17
2  2    A 2020-03-16         NaT
3  2    B 2020-03-18  2020-03-18
4  3    A 2020-07-16  2020-07-16
6  4    A 2020-02-13         NaT
7  4    B 2020-02-14  2020-02-14
```

P.S. And you can of course `reset_index(drop=True)` afterwards, if you want to make it look exactly like your expected output

**Update** If you want to keep rows where both dates are `np.nan`, you can add another boolean mask and apply it with `|`:

```
# the original condition DATE_VIEW <= DATE_ACCEPT
m1 = df['DATE_VIEW'].le(df.groupby('ID')['DATE_ACCEPT'].transform('max'))

# both dates are np.nan
m2 = df[['DATE_VIEW', 'DATE_ACCEPT']].isna().all(axis=1)

df.loc[m1|m2]
```

Comment: thank you @perl and if for instance I have for a unique ID both DATE_VIEW and DATE_ACCEPT null and I would like to keep them?